# Configuring JMX for Cassandra correctly

Tags: cassandra

So my Cassandra cluster is running properly but I cannot execute remote commands using JMX

i.e 
execute nodetool commands on other nodes from one node.

I have added this line in cassandra-env.sh

```
JVM_OPTS = "$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=my_host_ip"
```

Are there any more configurations that I have to change ?

Please let me know 
THanks.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Cassandra are you using?

By default JMX is enabled in version > 2.1 but defaults to Local JMX connections only.

To use remote JMX connections, please change value of `LOCAL_JMX` in cassandra-env.sh

i.e `LOCAL_JMX=false`

Hope it helps!